# Why can't I post on Super User?

Tags: support

I've looked at the other posts on this topic with no luck. I have a question that I'm trying to ask and answer myself. I typed it all up, but when I click `Post Your Question and Answer` it just reloads the page. All of my input is still there, and there's no error message or anything. I've tried clearing the cookies, logging out and back in, and even restarting my computer. The post does not appear in my search history. I'm not exactly sure where to turn from here.

---

It appears that when submitting *this* question I **do** get an error: `You can only post once every 40 minutes.` So I guess my other post registered as posted despite not actually working? It doesn't show up in my profile nor when I search from an incognito tab.

Comment: To clarify, I wrote this post 40 minutes ago. It only let me post just now.

Comment: You have no bans or blocks that I can see. It looks to just be a rate limiting feature. Your last question was [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1264574/how-can-i-track-my-chromebook) asked almost 1.5 hours ago (18:53, time now 20:21)

Comment: You haven't asked and deleted a whole bunch of questions recently have you?

Comment: @Mokubai Then perhaps there's something wrong with the error message, because there was none at all. Although now that this one has successfully posted I am seeing the 40 minutes error on my Q&A.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I have not

Comment: Any chance other users are sharing your IP address?

Comment: "Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)"

Comment: @DavidPostill That would explain why it wouldn't let me post, since I'm posting from a university. But regardless, there still should have been some message that appeared letting me know.

Comment: Please post a link in the comments to the question you open on meta about this so others interested in following your bug report can follow it.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Thanks for the reminder. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302890/227921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm posting from a university.

It is likely that may be others posting with the same public IP address elsewhere on the SE network.

In that case the IP address is rate limited not the individual users:

> **Asking**
>
> Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on
>   the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account.
>   If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by
>   the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)
>
> [image]

Source [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

> But regardless, there still should have been some message that appeared letting me know.

The error message could be better. You might want to raise a [feature-request](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: >The error message could be better.

I'm saying there was no error message whatsoever. But I'll raise a [tag:bug] on there instead. Thanks for the insight.